# How do I use the camera view for Viewport Render Animation?

Tags: rendering, camera

View > Viewport Render Animation does not use the camera. Is it possible for it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to a classical *Render > Render Animation*, if you want to render through *View > Viewport Render Animation*, you need to first be in camera view (press <kbd>0</kbd>).